# How to do this reaction - adding 2 different groups to an alkyne with 2 terminal hydrogens?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

[image: How to add a methyl group and an ethyl group to an alkyne with 2 terminal hydrogen separately.]

How to add a methyl group and an ethyl group to an alkyne with 2 terminal hydrogens separately?

Answer (score 3):

No catalytic hydrogenation. Doing a sequential alkylation of the starting acetylene using sodamide and liquid ammonia with the appropriate alkyl bromide will do the trick.  Be sure to only use one equivalent of the first alkylating agent.  It doesn't matter whether you use $\ce{MeBr}$ or $\ce{EtBr}$ first.

[image]